# EF Core Power Tools: Missing setter for collections

Tags: automapper, ef-power-tools, automapper-12, ef-core-power-tools

Is there a way to have the EF Core Power Tools create setters for collections, like so:

```csharp
class Parent
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; } // Setter is missing
}
```

The setter would be extremely useful with AutoMapper.
Otherwise we have to explicitly specify the mapping like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037827/automapper-nested-collections-without-setter).

Comment: That's not needed in newer AM versions.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu We're using AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore 9.0.0, AutoMapper 12.0.0, AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 12.0.0. I see there's an AutoMapper 12.0.1 package available now, but you wrote "newer AM versions", so that shouldn't be causing this? The properties aren't mapped.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I see you're a LINQPad user as well. ;) I just tried to reproduce this issue in LINQPad, but couldn't. But without the setters, we're getting empty collections in our application. I'll try to figure out what's causing this and provide sample code to reproduce the problem.